# WPF Auto-assign styles to children through parent style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xaml-resources

I got several `StackPanels` in my application which want their children to apply certain styles:

```
<StackPanel.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource SettingLabel}" />
    <Style TargetType="DockPanel" BasedOn="{StaticResource SettingRow}" />
    <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource SettingCheckBox}" />
    <Style TargetType="PasswordBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource DialogPasswordBox}" />
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource DialogTextBox}" />
</StackPanel.Resources>
```

Instead of writing these 5 lines over and over again I though of giving the `StackPanel` itself a style which will apply those and therefore reduce redundancy.

It is not possible to set `Resources` in a style setter because it's no dependency property:

```
<Style x:Key="SettingPanel" TargetType="StackPanel">
    <Setter Property="Resources">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource SettingLabel}" />
            <Style TargetType="DockPanel" BasedOn="{StaticResource SettingRow}" />
            <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource SettingCheckBox}" />
            <Style TargetType="PasswordBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource DialogPasswordBox}" />
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource DialogTextBox}" />
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

So is there any other way to do this without having to set the styles on every child and repeat the *assignment* styles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define styles in `Style.Resources` of `StackPanel`. These will be applied to all the children of `StackPanel` using SettingPanel as style.

```
<Style x:Key="SettingPanel" TargetType="StackPanel">
    <Style.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource SettingLabel}" />
            <Style TargetType="DockPanel" BasedOn="{StaticResource SettingRow}" />
            <Style TargetType="CheckBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource SettingCheckBox}" />
            <Style TargetType="PasswordBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource DialogPasswordBox}" />
            <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource DialogTextBox}" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```